# Can't connect a computer to the internet in a networking simulation

Tags: networking

I can't figure out what is wrong with my IPS and gateways, everything is working fine except meson's PC can't connect to the internet.

[Here is a picture of the network interface where I have to connect computers to the internet and to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Khs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, took me a while to figure it out. But all I had to do was choose a non private subnet for the local area network where meson and ion are. So instead of using an IP address like 192.168.1.0/24 which are IP addresses mostly used for local area networks. I had to use ip addresses like 128.100.5.0/24 for example.